# Download pdf in current page not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor, href

Currently below code is working fine but i want the PDF to be downloaded on same page instead of getting opened in a window(same/different).
Is it possible?Any help would be appreciated

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {

          $('a[href]#hide-link').each(function () {
              var href = this.href;

              $(this).removeAttr('href').css('cursor', 'pointer').click(function () {
                  if (href.toLowerCase().indexOf("#") >= 0) {

                  } else {
                      window.open(href, '_self');


                  }
              });
          });

    }, 500);
});
</script>
```

HTMl :

```
<a href="example.pdf" download="example" id="hide-link">Download</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            setTimeout(function () {

                $('a[href]#hide-link').each(function () {
                    var href = this.href;
                    $(this).removeAttr('href').css('cursor', 'pointer').click(function () {
                        if (href.toLowerCase().indexOf("#") >= 0) {

                        } else {
                            window.location = href;
                        }
                    });
                });

            }, 500);
        });
```